# Change in Facebook graph api, posts?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm making an app with uses the facebook graph api to fetch a users posts, like this:

`[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"2439131959/posts" andParams:params andDelegate:self];`

This worked for a couple of months now, but like 3 days ago it suddenly stopped working.

After an error log from the api it gave me the following:

```
Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x5e3da10 {error=<CFBasicHash 0x5e2ec50 [0x16fa3e0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 2,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x5e2ea90 [0x16fa3e0]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x5e2efa0 [0x16fa3e0]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
    3 : <CFString 0x5e2f0a0 [0x16fa3e0]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x5e2f020 [0x16fa3e0]>{contents = "An access token is required to request this resource."}
}
```

It says something that an access token is required, but this wasn't always the case, wasn't it? It always worked and I didn't changed any code...

Any help would be great! Thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook did change something: developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509 . That's a bummer :(.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything has changed, but at least for a public Facebook page, it's easier than you might think to get an access token.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660728/embed-activity-feed-of-a-public-facebook-page-without-forcing-user-to-login-allo/26722934#26722934).