# Embed activity feed of a public Facebook page without forcing user to login/allow

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, embed

This is similar to questions asked several times before, but no matter what I read, I'm still confused.

I have a public Facebook page, like White Collar for example, whose activity feed I need to embed into my Android app. I understand how to get the app-id and app-secret, but I don't understand how to get the short-lived access token, which I understand is necessary to get a long-lived access token.

From what I understand, which can quite possibly be wrong, the user has to login through the app to get a short-lived access token, but I don't want any user to have to login to view the activity feed.

Once I have that, how do I then use it to bring this activity feed into my app?

The Facebook documentation for this is terrible so I need some help.

If it or anything else requires site-specific permissions, I have access to the site in question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get the activity feed of a public Facebook page, like White Collar, follow these steps:

1) Get your App-id and App-secret by choosing an existing app or creating a new one at this url:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
```

2) Get an access token by making a GET request to this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + APP_ID + "&client_secret=" + APP_SECRET + "&grant_type=client_credentials
```

3) Get the page-id of your fan page. To do this, you need the page-name. Go to your fan page on facebook and look at the url. It will have this form:

```
https://www.facebook.com/{fan-page-name}
```

Once you have that, make a GET request to this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{fan-page-name}?access_token={access-token}
```

It will return a bunch of JSON. You're looking for the first "id" element. This is your page-id.

4) Get the fan page JSON data with a GET request to this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/" + page-id + "/feed?access_token=" + URLEncoder.encodeUTF8(access-token)
```

To avoid having exceptions thrown, I had to use `URLEncoder.encodeUTF8().`
The data you're looking for is under the "data" element.

I wasn't able to find anything that would do the JSON parsing of the Facebook feed for me, but I did find this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/) that will do a lot of the formatting for you to make it look like Facebook.

Hope that helps anyone else trying to do this.

Comment: +1 for the link to the Android Hive article!  I was able to easily adapt that to fit my needs in my Android app.

Comment: For step3, it is already not supported now. And it will give out error:
{"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104,"fbtrace_id":"FEz1d5Z\/Gnz"}}

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that! It is still supported for apps using the older api. I wish I had time to debug and figure out a new solution for you. On part 2 of Step 3, you might try using `URLEncoder.encodeUTF8(<facebookAccessToken>)` to make sure it's getting outputted in the right format.

Comment: Step 2 seems to be broken as well, now :(

Comment: It seems like facebook requires app approval before they will give you 'Page Public Content Access.' I now get this error after using a valid access token for a brand new, unapproved app: ""(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review."