# Testing app on localhost, getting the posts by user id returns an empty array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

My code:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'=>$clientId, 
    'app_secret'=>$clientSecret, 
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
    ]);
$uid = 'my_uid';
try {
  $response = $fb->get('/'.$uid.'/posts', $clientId.'|'.$clientSecret);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

var_dump($response->getDecodedBody());
```

`$uid` is ID of my own facebook page, there is have the posts.
App domain in the settings is `localhost`, site URL `http://localhost/FB`.

Output of var_dump:

> object(stdClass)[10]   public 'data' => 
>       array (size=0)
>         empty

Comment: Where is the part where the user grants your app the necessary permission to read their posts?

Comment: How can I ask the user for permission to `user_posts`?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

Comment: first get the access_token which will contain the required permissions that will allow you to read posts, then pass that access_token while calling that api.

Comment: It turns out that I need to get posts from a public page. This was simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660728/embed-activity-feed-of-a-public-facebook-page-without-forcing-user-to-login-allo