# Facebook graph API page_id/feed showing published content in Visitors Post on Facebook page?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook Graph API me/accounts i need the list of pages created by user and by using page_id i want to publish content over particular Facebook page. i successfully get the pages list by giving manage_pages permission and successfully publish video on Facebook page by using page_id/feed graph API,but my problem is that particular publish contents are showing on Visitors post on Facebook page,i want that this particular content showed on Facebook page wall.

Comment: Check out this this may helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660728/embed-activity-feed-of-a-public-facebook-page-without-forcing-user-to-login-allo

Comment: @Bosco Sabin...thank for your feedback but my problem is not about sharing without login/allow.My problem is when i am sharing content on Facebook page which i created, content successfully  shared over Facebook  page but it will show in visitors post rather than Facebook page feed or post. please see this link.[https://www.facebook.com/Sparkofftest-2028442130769685/posts_to_page/]

Comment: use a page token instead of a user token

Comment: @luschn.. with graph api explorer i can use page token... but how can use page token with android..currently i do this by         AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

Comment: by using the me/accounts endpoint with the manage_pages and publish_pages permission

Comment: @luschn...yes i am getting access token from me/accounts api but how can i use this token in my android app.. AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(); this give me user access token..should i set this like AccesToken accToken=new AccessToken("token","fbid","user_id",)